# Basic R Shiny Plotting questions, 3 variables to plot

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I'm kinda new to all this and an working on a a simple shiny app with which plots the income and population via water/power consumption. I basically want to plot the water/power consumption based on population and income levels. I know my ui.R seems ok, the issue is the plot I have with server.R. Trying to make it as simple as I can

Here are my errors and codes. Thanks in advance for all the help

```
    Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6960
Warning in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
Stack trace (innermost first):
    103: plot.window
    102: localWindow
    101: plot.default
    100: plot
     99: renderPlot [/Users/****/server.R#12]
     89: <reactive:plotObj>
     78: plotObj
     77: origRenderFunc
     76: output$plot_data
      1: runApp[enter image description here][1]
```

for ui.R

```
ui.R

library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Title
  titlePanel("Los Angeles Water Usage"),
  p("The main purpose of the Application is to dynamically represent the Water use in the City of Los Angeles based on different factors. Factors may include income level and area of residence. Income and Water consumption data was collected on FY 2015.", align="left"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      #Select Input for Charting Water or Power
      selectInput("commodity", "Select Water or Power Consumption:",
                  choices = colnames(WaterPopulationIncome[4:5]), selected = "Water"),

      #Sets the X axis variable
      selectInput("xvar", "Select x-axis Variable",
                  choices = colnames(WaterPopulationIncome[2:3]), selected = "Total.Population"),

      #Sets the Y axis variable
      selectInput("yvar", "Select y-axis Variable",
                  choices = colnames(WaterPopulationIncome[2:3]), selected = "Median_Household_income"),



    # Show a plot 
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("plot_data")
    )
  )
))
```

for server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#Scatter Plot
     my_reactive <- reactive({
       WaterPopulationIncome[sample(nrow(WaterPopulationIncome), input$commodity),]
     })

    output$plot_data <- renderPlot({
      plot(my_reactive, x = input$xvar, y = input$yvar)

  })

})
```

Sample df

```
Zip Total.Population    Median_Household_income Water.Use   Power.Use   place_geoid Median.Age  Average.Household.Size  Mean_income
90001   57110          33887                        15.08        318    16000US0644000  26.6    4.4 42625
90001   57110          33887                        14.03        352    16000US0644000  26.6    4.4 42625
90001   57110          33887                        14.53        310    16000US0644000  26.6    4.4 42625
```

Error Page

Comment: Try with `plot(my_reactive(), ...`

Comment: And `WaterPopulationIncome[,input$commodity]`

Comment: Thank you!  Where do I add  WaterPopulationIncome[,input$commodity]?   Also, I'm getting a page error 'need finite xlim values'

Comment: Jsut replace `WaterPopulationIncome[sample(nrow(WaterPopulationIncome), input$commodity),]`

Comment: Thanks! I've replaced it and the error is giving is that "need finite xlim values", My understanding for xlim is that it's supposed to be the label for the x-axis, is the correct?

Comment: What about `plot(x = WaterPopulationIncome[,input$xvar], y = WaterPopulationIncome[,input$yvar], fill=my_reactive())`?

Comment: apologies for the late reply, i think i'm close. since it my data was a data frame input$xx should be set as.numeric. this is the reason it's asking for the xlim and ylim values. All I need to figure out now is why the chart is grey. Thanks